# ExecutorService InvokeAll for hybrid datatype

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, invokeall

I am new trying to invoke multiple multiple threads with varied return types, using ExecutorService. I need to wait for all threads to complete, before I proceed. I am able to do it using homogeneous return types, but want to use heterogeneous return types.

Below is my sample code snippet:

```
@RestController
public class ApplicationController {

@GetMapping
public String HelloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Inside Thread main");

    Callable<String> callableTask = () -> {
        return invokeThread1();
    };

    Callable<String> callableTask2 = () -> {
        return invokeThread2();
    };

    List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Inside Thread main - 1 ");

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    System.out.println("Inside Thread main - 2");

    tasks.add(callableTask);
    tasks.add(callableTask2);


    try {
        List<Future<String>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

        for (Future<String> f : futures) {
            result.append(f.get());
            System.out.println(" result ::: " + result);
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Inside Thread main - 5 " + result.toString());
    return result.toString();
}

private String invokeThread1() {

    final String uri = "http://localhost:8082";

    return invokeService(uri).getBody();
}

private String invokeThread2() {

    final String uri = "http://localhost:8083";

    return invokeService(uri).getBody();
}

private ResponseEntity<String> invokeService(final String uri) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    return result;
}

}
```

Imagine the return type of **invokeThread1 is String**, while that of **invokeThread2 is Integer**. Please help me with the requisite changes.

Comment: An easy (but ugly) solution is to have `Callable<Object>` as the type and make sure you know exactly what you (or the contributors) are doing and then parse the result back in the format that you would want it to, in the order in which you put them in.

Comment: Another way would be to use an interface that is common to all the return types of the tasks.